# Can I request a new Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, area-51, stack-exchange

My girlfriend is a civil engineer, and she often asks me for ideas, comments, or tips on her projects. The problem is that I'm not an engineer, so I can't understand those projects. She uses AutoCAD to draw houses and other buildings, and I think it would be very useful to ask something online or on Stack Overflow like "Hey guys, this is my project. What do you think? Do I need a window here? Should I put the bathroom here?".

I haven't seen a site that meets these needs. I think it would be nice to have a `civilengineering-stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Please take a look at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and perhaps propose such a site. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that the [subtly-named 'engineering' site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8186/engineering) *might* be appropriate. (But I've got no insight into, or understanding of, the various disciplines within the field of engineering, so I could be way off track...)

Comment: how i can propose things at Area51? it say at least 5 reputation on Area 51 to ask a question i can't do it  David maybe you can do it for me ? i will follow the question on there ?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) page, it *tells* you... =) Also, no: I am ***not*** proposing a site for a subject in which I have neither knowledge, interest or inclination of following.

Comment: ok i will wait 5 reputation

Comment: If you link another stackexchange acct with over 200 rep you'll get 100 rep there (at least that's true for some sites and I think it's true for all).

Comment: confirming your email on Area 51 will give you +50 rep, fyi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Head over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) where you can propose a new site (or see if one exists already). There's the DIY/Home Improvement site which may cross some lines, however.

There is also an "[Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8186/engineering)" proposal still in "Definition" phase, although I realise Engineering is a wide-ranging field.